# Usage of かしら as a standalone phrase

Tags: usage

In the anime 少女革命ウテナ (Revolutionary Girl Utena) one of the shadow girls often says

> かしら、かしら。ご存知かしら？

which is translated in the subtitles as "I wonder, I wonder. Do you know what I wonder?".

I'm familiar with adding かしら after the predicate but I've not come across it as a standalone word before. Is this usage standard? If someone asks me, for example, "do you think my cunning plan will work?", and I'm not sure of the answer, can I just respond with かしら? It feels unlikely to me.

Unrelated, but I also have no idea how ご存知 works in this phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These かしら are meaningless except that they add some rhythm. This pattern is known as [三三七拍子](http://www.worldfolksong.com/calendar/japan/san-san-nana.html). Note that those shadow girls talk fairly theatrically, playing the role similar to western clowns ([video](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm14748099)), so they don't have to speak normally. In English, maybe something like "sing-*a-ling-a-ling*" or "see you later *alligator*" is somewhat close to this.

ご存じかしら literally means "(I wonder,) Do you know?", not "Do you know what I wonder?" But when translating a catchphrase like this, rhythm is more important than the semantic fidelity, so I don't think the translator made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

mostly women use the word かしら when they are not sure about a certain thing. For example 今日は雨が降るかしら？ means i wonder if it rains today. Men would say 今日は雨が降るかな？ in the same situation, if men say かしら at the end of the sentence it sounds a bit weird.
With regard to 「かしら、かしら。ご存知かしら？」 does not make any sense in terms of grammer. This is a particular phrase that author of this anime wants to add some unique feature to this particular character like cliche but as everyday conversation, this does not make sense at all.